# setInterval with (this)

Tags: javascript, setinterval

Please, someone can explain me what is the meaning of **(this)** at the end of the function in a setInterval :

```
function Klass(name) {
      this.name = name;
      this.handle = null;

      this.startTimer = function() {

        this.handle = setInterval(function(obj) {

          return(function() {
            alert(obj.name);
            });

          }(this), 5000); // <-------------------- (this)

      }
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The use of `this` in the construct is intended to preserve the meaning of `this` at the point `setInterval` is called for the actual call back that is executed at the given interval.  Without the manual preservation `this` would become the owner of the function at the point `setInterval` was called.

Here's a very nice article on this subject

- http://www.quirksmode.org/js/this.html

Another way this could be done which may be a bit clearer is the following

```
var self = this
this.handle = setInterval(function() { alert(self.Name); }, 5000);
```

Comment: Thanks. I realized that 'obj' is replaced with 'this', e.g. if i put another variable like '(another)' at the end, 'obj' is interpreted as 'another', is this posible?

Comment: @dnielF yes it's possible to use any value there instead of `this` so long as it has a `name` property